# gzip with execlp in fork process

Tags: c, exec, gzip, fork

I have a problem i don't know how to solve in my code. I have to compress with gzip several arguments received form the command-line.

But i have to introduce in the command line the route and not the file. The sample i have prepared is working well but i'm indicating the name of the file and this is not correct.

Can you help me how to indicate the route and not the file? in the execlp. The route is argv[]  but i don't know exactly how to build the sentence.

The code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int p,pid[p];
    int fills;
    int ret=0;
    char msg[100];
    int status;
    char filename[30];

    if (argc>1)
    fills=atoi(argv[p]);
    if (argc==1)
    {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Creem N paràmetres
    for(p=1; p<argc; p++)
    {

        pid[p] = fork();
        if (pid[p]<0)
            error("Error");

        if (pid[p]==0)
        {
        memset(filename,0,sizeof(filename));
        snprintf(filename,30,"ex1a.c");
        ret=execlp("gzip", "gzip", "-9", "-f", filename, NULL);
            if (ret < 0)
            {
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        printf("Process %d created process %d compressed file %s \n",getppid(),getpid(),argv[p]);
        exit(p);
    }
    else
    wait(status);
}
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*route*"?

Comment: Which options do you want to pass via the command line (example?). How should the `gzip` command you want the program to `exec*()`ute look like exactly?

Comment: `argv[1]` is a reference to the 1st option passed to the program, `argv[2]` to the 2nd. .. and so on. The number of options can be found in `argc`.

Comment: It was my mistake i passed as parameter a directory and the file inside. For instance: /bin/bash and the result appears in the /tmp folder with the zip file. The first block of my question is completed now i have to solve the second part "has finished".If i put the print after the wait(status) then my "pid" process is lost!!

Comment: When you say 'route', do you mean 'path'?  As in, the path name for the password file on Unix is `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: I Jonathan with the last code edited it works pretty well. Now all the zips remain in the tmp folder as xxxx.1 xxxxx.2 xxxxx.3.